# Read large amount of sectors into buffer to submit bio in kernel module for kernel 6.0+

Tags: c, kernel

I'm trying to read multiple sectors into a large buffer in a kernel module, then write to same disk

```
void *pg = NULL;

static void end_block_io_op(struct bio *bio)
{
    u64 *p = (u64 *) bio->bi_private;
    // pr_alert("0x%llx\n", p[0]); // prints 512-byte page (the buffer)
    pr_alert("0x%016llx\n", p[0]); // prints 16 bytes from 512-byte page (buffer)
    bio_put(bio);
}

static void end_block_io_op_w(struct bio *bio)
{
    u64 *p = (u64 *) bio->bi_private;
    pr_alert("0x%016llx\n", p[255]); // prints 2040'th sector
    bio_put(bio);
}


void readPage(struct block_device *bdev, unsigned long sector, unsigned int size, struct page *page)
{
    struct bio *bio = bio_alloc(bdev, 1, REQ_OP_READ, GFP_KERNEL);
    pg = page_address(page);
    bio->bi_iter.bi_sector = sector;
    bio->bi_private = pg;
    bio->bi_end_io  = end_block_io_op;
    bio_add_page(bio, page, size, 0);
    submit_bio(bio);
}

void writePage(struct block_device *bdev, unsigned long sector, unsigned int size, struct page *page)
{
    struct bio *bio = bio_alloc(bdev, 1, REQ_OP_WRITE, GFP_KERNEL);
    bio->bi_iter.bi_sector = sector;
    bio->bi_private = pg;
    bio->bi_end_io = end_block_io_op_w;
    bio_add_page(bio, page, size, 0);
    submit_bio(bio);
}

static int __init sbull_init(void)
{
    u32 device = MKDEV(8, 0); // 253 is dm-crypt but on a non-crypt drive, sda is 8
    struct block_device *bdev = blkdev_get_by_dev(device, FMODE_READ, NULL);
    struct page *page = alloc_page(GFP_KERNEL);

    readPage(bdev, 0, 512, page);
    writePage(bdev, 2040, 512, page);
    return 0;
}

static void sbull_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "read_sector module removed\n");
}

module_init(sbull_init);
module_exit(sbull_exit);
```

This reads 1 sector but write does not work either. My goal is allocating buffer from `kmalloc` but not sure how to add buffer to bio to submit. only know how to add a page.

I'm basically trying to read a large amount of sectors into a buffer to submit a bio to read. then use the same buffer to write back to a different sector.